# Jquery push multiple selectors into an object at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to push the name and diet fields into a single object at once such that it console.log out something like

```
group1: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: "some diet"
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: "some other diet"
        name: "some other name"

group2: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: "some diet"
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: "some other diet"
        name: "some other name"
    [2]: Object
        diet: "another diet"
        name: "another name"
    so on....
```

However, I'm getting some logic error that causes the console.log to be this:

```
group1: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: undefined
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: undefined
        name: "some other name"

group2: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: undefined
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: undefined
        name: "some other name"
    [2]: Object
        diet: undefined
        name: "another name"
    so on....
```

I'm relatively new to jquery/javascript and php (3 weeks so don't stab me too much) and afaics there doesn't seem to be any problem with it. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
var tso = {
            group1: [],
            group2: [],
            ogroup: [],
            igroup: [],
            others: []
        };

for (var k in tso) {
    if (tso.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        var nameField = $("input[id*="+k+"]");
        var dietField = $("select[id*="+k+"] option:selected");
        $.each($(nameField, dietField), function() {
            tso[k].push({name: $(this).closest('input').val(), diet: $(this).closest('select').val()});
        });
    }
};

console.log(tso);
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's no need for each, you're already iterating, and `$(nameField, dietField)` just seems wrong ?

Comment: I'm iterating the arrays in the tso array, but the each is for every input and select that is available in the html. About the $(nameField, dietField), yeah I've been told it is wrong, but I don't really know how to iterate for 2 different elements at once. Saw this: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ and tried to apply it

Comment: Edited my example to show what I'm trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, played around more and found a method to do this. As I have an equal number of input and select elements, I could just iterate through which ever element comes first. In my case, input is always before the select element, hence I can just use the .next() command to get the next element.

```
for (var k in tso) {
    if (tso.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        $("input[id*="+k+"]").each(function() {
            tso[k].push({name: $(this).val(), diet: $(this).next().val()});
        });
    }
};
```

This consoles out

```
group1: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: "American"
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: "Western"
        name: "some other name"

group2: Array[some number]
    [0]: Object
        diet: "Asian"
        name: "some name"
    [1]: Object
        diet: "No preference"
        name: "some other name"
    [2]: Object
        diet: "Vegetarian"
        name: "another name"
so on....
```

In the event that the elements are not next to each other, you can use .nextUntil("selector") to select the next input/select/element

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `for` as below:

```
for (var k in tso) {
    if (tso.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        var nameField = $("input[id*="+k+"]").val();
        var dietField = $("select[id*="+k+"]").val();        
        tso[k].push({name: nameField, diet: dietField });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but only 1 object was pushed into the array. I have multiple input and select to be used